# How to remove a small box at the bottom of my coding window in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R and after running some code a small grey box appeared at the bottom left of my coding window. It covers text when I try to type in the bottom line of the coding area and does not interact with the cursor/is not able to be clicked on. Has anyone encountered this before?

[Image of my coding window with a small box at the bottom left.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woomz.png)

[image]

Comment: nope, does it move as you resize the panes?

Comment: No, it doesn't move. If I make the coding pane longer, it stays in the middle instead of moving down with bottom left. I also did just notice that the box is only in this tab - I have another R Script open and that one does not have a box.

Comment: That seems like a bug that needs to be filed to RStudio

Comment: That also seems to have been mentioned on the RStudio community site https://community.rstudio.com/t/small-white-rectangle-appearing-on-upper-left-side-of-rstudio-what-the-heck/145072/9

Answer (score 1):

I made this gremlin go away by closing the edit window in which it had been a minor visual annoyance for dozens of RStudio sessions.  When I reopened the file for editing, hey presto, the gremlin had disappeared.

My best-guess as to the origins of this gremlin is that it is a dysfunctional remnant of an affordance for the spell-corrector.  In the screenshots below: a wavy red underline indicates a word that is not found in the spell-corrector's dictionary.  Somewhat surprisingly,
the spell-corrector's GUI affordance is not found by clicking on the underline, nor by mouse-hovering on the underlined word. At least not on my Win11 installation.  YMMV.

[image: Small-box affordance near a wavy-underlined word]

Before I write anything more about this very minor but annoying GUI defect I want to say

"Thank you, thank you, thank you, mille grazie to the RStudio GUI team!!!  Well done!"

Returning to my partial-localisation of this gremlin: a left-click
on the small-box that's displayed somewhat below and to the right of the wavy underline will sometimes (but not always) reveal affordances for spell-correction options such as "Add to user dictionary".

[image: Spell-correction options appear after clicking on the small-box]

The small-box will sometimes (but not always) remain at a fixed location within the edit-display-window when the underlying text is scrolled -- and it may continue to appear even after the wavy-underlined word is no longer visible.

[image: Small box may continue to appear after the wavy-underlined text is no longer visible]

Editing the text when the small-box is displayed may convert it into
a dysfunctional gremlin.  I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour but
I'm pretty sure the gremlin-creation process is associated, somehow, to edits in which the wavy-underlined word has been deleted or modified.

I have opened a new issue at  https://community.rstudio.com/t/small-white-rectangle-gremlin-partial-localisation/156041

I've had enough "fun" for now with trying to find a plausible origin-story for this gremlin ;-)